# Cross search two dataframes with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have encountered a problem that I have not seen before.
The situation is as follows
I have 2 dataframes somewhat different from each other:

- `cc_etn` has the tickets with refund
- `etn` has the information of the users who have purchased

I want to search by the id the information of the users who were refunded. What I did was to make a list in `cc_etn` and so iterate over  `etn` with the method 'df.loc' to find them, however I get an empty DataFrame.
The interesting thing here is that to find the user in `etn`, there are 4 columns that have to be equal to those I have in `cc_etn`. Now, if I put 4 conditions to `df.loc` I get empty DataFrame, and if I put a condition if I get the values I want but still missing 3 other columns that would have to be equal to find the user, I also tried to make a chain of `df.loc` to find them but I also get empty, so my code looks something like this:

```
cc_etn = pd.read_csv(CONTRA CARGOS APLICADOS .csv',dtype='str')
etn = pd.read_csv(query_result_2021-06-29T15_41_38.794753Z.csv')

#here I list the columns that are relevant to finding the user in etn.
fecha = list(cc_etn['Fecha de Transacción'])
tarjeta = list(cc_etn['Número de Tarjeta'])
monto_1 = list(cc_etn['Monto Publicado'])
codigo = list(cc_etn['Código de \nAutenticación']) 

#here I cycle through to find each user but they all come up empty
for i in range(len(monto):
  (duplicados.loc[(duplicados['created_at_day'] == fecha[i]) & 
  (duplicados['card_number']==tarjeta[i]) & (duplicados['amount'] == monto[i]) & 
  (duplicados['card_authorization']==codigo[i])]

#now if i print this if it works but i don't get what i want
duplicados.loc[duplicados['created_at_day'] == fecha[1]
duplicados.loc[duplicados['card_number']==tarjeta[1]
duplicados.loc[duplicados['amount'] == monto[1]
duplicados.loc[duplicados['card_authorization']==codigo[1]

#and if I do this i have again a empty DataFrame
x = duplicados.loc[duplicados['created_at_day'] == fecha[1]
y = x.loc[x['card_number']==tarjeta[1]
```

I have this error too:

```
#SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a 
#slice from a DataFrame
```

Comment: This is the reason **`join`** exists. Join your dataframes on those four columns.

Comment: Chaining four `.loc[]` calls will give spaghetti code, also needlessly cause copies as you found out, and you can't assign to them. The whole point of the pandas 'SettingWithCopyWarning' is a very loud "Don't do this!". Use `join`

Comment: As @smci says, join is your friend.  
Please try to simplify the problem to a minimal example with artificial data that shows what you want and why what you have done fails. This makes it much easier for us to answer

Comment: At least join your dataframes on the 'id' columns (is that your index?), and edit to show us the updated code and snippet of output data. (Better still if you can figure out how to join on 'id' + some or all of your four columns. Ideally you want to get one-to-one correspondence. Then you won't need to 'search', you just look up the answer, already.)